# how to add minutes to datatime.time. Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime.time object:

```
A = datetime.time(15, 50)
```

How can I add 10 minutes so that :

```
B = A + (10min)
B = datetime.time(16, 0)
```

Thanks

Edit: Question is not a dup. It involves the transformation from date.time to datetime.datetime as shown by the answer.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the time is actually 23:55 at night?

Comment: @donkopotamus I expect datetime.time (0, 5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to transform your time into a fully fledged `datetime.datetime` before you can add your ten minutes

```
def add_delta(tme, delta):
    # transform to a full datetime first
    return (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), tme) + 
            delta).time()
```

Then

```
>>> add_delta(datetime.time(15, 50), datetime.timedelta(minutes=10))
datetime.time(16, 0)
```

This will roll times according to clock arithmetic.

```
>>> add_delta(datetime.time(23, 55), datetime.timedelta(minutes=10))
datetime.time(0, 5)
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to combine with datetime.date.today ? Isn't there a more straight forward answer?

Comment: @hernanavella No, there is not